# ERROR: column is of type bit but expression is of type boolean

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

The database have an attribute with type BIT(1) where the value can be '0'/'1',
I have an hibernate entity that have an attribute:

```java
  private Boolean attribute;
```

What i tried:

- Use @Type
- use Boolean/boolean
- use String
- Use a Converter
- Use a custom type(https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types)

But I only receive errors like

```
ERROR: column  is of type bit but expression is of type boolean
ERROR: column  is of type bit but expression is of type bytea
ERROR: column is of type bit but expression is of type various
ERROR: column is of type bit but expression is of type string
```

Comment: You should define the column in the database table as `boolean`, not `bit`

Comment: I cannot, it have a lot of dependencies with other teams to redefine the column

Comment: If the boolean value is '0' or '1', then you should be able to cast it in bit(1) in postgres : `SELECT '1' :: bit(1)`

Comment: Well, `boolean` values shouldn't be stored in a `bit` column to begin with. This should have been a `boolean` right from the start. You aren't using a `Bit` in Java either.

Comment: Do you need to update the column or just read it?

Comment: Both actions, also insert

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, I would try using the following `@Column` definition for your field:

```java
@Column(columnDefinition="bit")
private Boolean attribute;
```

If it doesn't work, although I am aware that you mentioned you tested it in your question, try defining a custom `@Type`. The idea is based on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309861/how-to-read-geography-values-using-hibernate/66626842#66626842), the [following test case](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/f61fbfe7b72ccf2ca0ac2e2c366230fdb93260e5/pgjdbc/src/test/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/BitFieldTest.java), and [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/) from Vlad Mihalcea.

Your custom type definition could be as follows:

```java
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class PostgresBit1Type
    extends ImmutableType<Boolean> {

  public PostgresBit1Type() {
    super(Boolean.class);
  }

  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[]{Types.BIT};
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean get(
      ResultSet rs,
      String[] names,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
      Object owner)
      throws SQLException {
    // The paradox is that the driver itself treats BIT(1) as boolean
    Boolean result = rs.getBoolean(names[0]);
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void set(
      PreparedStatement st,
      Point value,
      int index,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
      throws SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
      st.setNull(index, Types.BIT);
    } else {
      Object holder = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
        "org.postgresql.util.PGobject"
      );
      ReflectionUtils.invokeSetter(
        holder,
        "type",
        "bit"
      );
      ReflectionUtils.invokeSetter(
        holder,
        "value",
        value ? "1" : "0"
      );
      st.setObject(index, holder);
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the companion SO answer, the `Inmutable` class is taken from [this excellent article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/) from Vlad Mihalcea:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public abstract class ImmutableType<T> implements UserType {

  private final Class<T> clazz;

  protected ImmutableType(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(
      ResultSet rs,
      String[] names,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
      Object owner)
      throws SQLException {
    return get(rs, names, session, owner);
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(
      PreparedStatement st,
      Object value,
      int index,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
      throws SQLException {
    set(st, clazz.cast(value), index, session);
  }

  protected abstract T get(
      ResultSet rs,
      String[] names,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
      Object owner) throws SQLException;

  protected abstract void set(
      PreparedStatement st,
      T value,
      int index,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
      throws SQLException;


  @Override
  public Class<T> returnedClass() {
    return clazz;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
    return Objects.equals(x, y);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(Object x) {
    return x.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(Object value) {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Object o) {
    return (Serializable) o;
  }

  @Override
  public Object assemble(
      Serializable cached,
      Object owner) {
    return cached;
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(
      Object o,
      Object target,
      Object owner) {
    return o;
  }
}
```

Finally, define your `Boolean` field similar to:

```java
@Type(type = "your.packg.PostgresBit1Type")
@Column(columnDefinition = "bit")
public Boolean attribute;
```

I recommend to use `Boolean` and not `boolean` to appropriately handle `null`. values.

Although I think it should work I haven't tested the solution myself. I hope at least it gives you some clues to advance in the problem resolution.

Answer (score 0):

**

### First lets clarify things:

**

The **Java Boolean** represents a **single bit** value that can be **0 or 1** (False or True).

**Whereas** SQL defines an **SQL BIT type** that, unlike what you expect, can be used as a parameterized type to define a **fixed-length binary string** (not just 0 or 1 it can be **00000**, **00001**, **01010**... etc.).

so that's why it might bring you problems while you map them.

---

However, try this:

```
@Column(name = "columnName", columnDefinition="BIT")
private Boolean columnVariable;
```

or this:

```
@Type(type = "numeric_boolean")
private Boolean columnVariable;
```